# Create new dictionary if key is substring of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, substring

I have the following list and dictionary

```
lst = [
    'A_blue',
    'A_yellow',
    'A_green',
    'A_red',
    'B_blue',
    'B_yellow',
    'B_green',
    'B_red',
    'C_blue',
    'C_yellow',
    'C_green',
    'C_red'
]

dct = {'blue': 0.5, 'yellow': 0.1, 'green': 0.3, 'red': 0.8}
```

I would like to obtain a new dictionary where the keys are the elements in `lst`, and the values are the numbers in `dct` if the key is a substring of the element in `lst`.
Basically the output would be something like:

```
{'A_blue': 0.5, 'A_yellow': 0.1, 'A_green': 0.3, 'A_red': 0.8, 'B_blue': 0.5, ...}
```

I tried several ways, but I obtained only syntax errors and others; e.g.,

```
[v for k, v in dct.items() if k in e for e in lst]
```

gave me `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment`, which I understand.
But I didn't manage to find a solution, even though should not be that difficult.

Comment: There's a little error with your syntax in the last piece of code, let me see if i know how to fix it...

Comment: @Epsi95 Ah, there it is, thanks. Was not far away. You can add it as an answer, I would accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try dict comprehension

```py
{i: dct[k] for i in lst for k in dct if k in i}
```

```
{'A_blue': 0.5,
 'A_yellow': 0.1,
 'A_green': 0.3,
 'A_red': 0.8,
 'B_blue': 0.5,
 'B_yellow': 0.1,
 'B_green': 0.3,
 'B_red': 0.8,
 'C_blue': 0.5,
 'C_yellow': 0.1,
 'C_green': 0.3,
 'C_red': 0.8}
```

NOTE: A normal loop may be faster since `if k in i` effectively iterate `for k in dct`, so it would be better to use `break` like this

```py
d = {}
for i in lst:
    for k in dct:
        if k in i:
            d[i] = dct[k]
            break
            
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach iterates through all the keys in `dct` and checks it against all the values in `lst`. If it is a substring, a new key is initialized and the value from `dct` is set.

```
newdct = {}
for i in dct.keys():
    for j in lst:
        if j.find(i)!=-1:
            newdct[j] = dct[i]
```

**Output**

```
{'A_blue': 0.5, 'B_blue': 0.5, 'C_blue': 0.5, 'A_yellow': 0.1, 'B_yellow': 0.1, 'C_yellow': 0.1, 'A_green': 0.3, 'B_green': 0.3, 'C_green': 0.3, 'A_red': 0.8, 'B_red': 0.8, 'C_red': 0.8}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
lst = [
    'A_blue',
    'A_yellow',
    'A_green',
    'A_red',
    'B_blue',
    'B_yellow',
    'B_green',
    'B_red',
    'C_blue',
    'C_yellow',
    'C_green',
    'C_red'
]

dct = {'blue': 0.5, 'yellow': 0.1, 'green': 0.3, 'red': 0.8}

result = {x: dct[x[2:]] for x in lst}
print(result)
```

output

```
{'A_blue': 0.5, 'A_yellow': 0.1, 'A_green': 0.3, 'A_red': 0.8, 'B_blue': 0.5, 'B_yellow': 0.1, 'B_green': 0.3, 'B_red': 0.8, 'C_blue': 0.5, 'C_yellow': 0.1, 'C_green': 0.3, 'C_red': 0.8}
```